# TRACEBACK ERROR: NoResultFound: No row was found for one()

Tags: python, forms, jinja2, traceback

I am trying to store form entries into my database. I have built a RESTful api for each entry in my db (I have also built a CRUD api for the database which makes POST and GET very simple to do for the most part). I have a JINJA2 HTML template that I am using from a Pyramid Web Interface for the user to interact with. I must admit, I am new to this and have been attempting to follow models in the pyramid [tutorial](http://pyramid-blogr.readthedocs.org/en/latest/blog_create_and_update_view_src.html)s with no avail.

The Error that I am getting is, what I believe, due to the route being entered as a `assessment.name` instead of an `id`. The API accepts assessment.name and assessment.id. But the parameter in the api.assessment_retrieve() is triggering the wrong thing.This is what I believe due to the `assessment = api.retrieve_assessment(request.route_url('assessment', id=id))` because when I place an actual `id` in the api, I get a result and all works.

2. There has to be a better method for grabbing the assessment_id from the `form` page, right?

I have created an extra route_uri `/done` designated for the purposes of storing the form submission and keeping a user on the same page, instead of a 202 page <-- but after as submission, I am still getting 202 (likely due to the HTTPCreate() function).

2. Is there a way to `return` routing the user back to the template?

Code:
**view.py**

```
@view_config(route_name='done', renderer='templates/assessment_form.jinja2')
def form(request):
    with transaction.manager:
        username = request.params['username']
        firstname = request.params['firstname']
        lastname = request.params['lastname']
        email = request.params['email']
        user = api.create_user(username, firstname, lastname, email)
        assessment = (request.route_url('assessment', id=id)) # <--- ISSUE
        assessment_results = api.create_assessment_results(user, assessment)
        transaction.commit()
        return HTTPCreated(location=request.route_url('user', id=id)) # <-- redirect so the user keeps working on the form
```

**route uri**
(all the entities follow the user route example)

```
config.add_route('done', '/done')  

config.add_route('users', '/users')
config.add_route('user', '/users/{id:\d+}')
```

**template**

```
<form method='POST' action='/done'>
  <dl class='user_form'>
    <dt><label for = 'username'> Username </label></dt>
    <dd>{{ forms.input('username') }}</dd>
    <dt><label for = 'firstname'> Firstname </label></dt>
    <dd>{{ forms.input('firstname') }}</dd>
    <dt><label for = 'lastname'> Lastname </label></dt>
    <dd>{{ forms.input('lastname') }}</dd>
    <dt><label for = 'email'> Email </label></dt>
    <dd>{{ forms.input('email') }}</dd>
    <dd><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></dd> 
  </dl>

  <dl class='category_form'>
    <dt><label for = 'category_rating_int'> Situation Awareness </label></dt>
    <dd>{{ forms.input('category_rating_int', type=category_rating_int) }}</dd>
    <dt><label for = 'category_rating_int'> Decision Making </label></dt>
    <dd>{{ forms.input('category_rating_int', type=category_rating_int) }}</dd>
    <dt><label for = 'category_rating_int'> Teamwork and Communication  </label></dt>
    <dd>{{ forms.input('category_rating_int', type=category_rating_int) }}</dd>
    <dt><label for = 'category_rating_int'> Leadership </label></dt>
    <dd>{{ forms.input('category_rating_int', type=category_rating_int) }}</dd>
    <dd><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></dd>
  </dl>

 # more entities

  </form>
```

**ERROR:**

```
2015-09-25 00:35:16,674 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][Dummy-4] SELECT assessments.assessment_id AS assessments_assessment_id, assessments.name AS assessments_name, assessments.text AS assessments_text, assessments.created_on AS assessments_created_on, assessments.edited AS assessments_edited, assessments.user_id AS assessments_user_id, assessments.video_id AS assessments_video_id 
FROM assessments 
WHERE assessments.name = ?
2015-09-25 00:35:16,674 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][Dummy-4] ('http://0.0.0.0:6543/assessments/%3Cbuilt-in%20function%20id%3E',)
2015-09-25 00:35:16,675 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][Dummy-4] ROLLBACK
2015-09-25 00:35:16,677 ERROR [pyramid_debugtoolbar][Dummy-4] Exception at http://0.0.0.0:6543/done
traceback url: http://0.0.0.0:6543/_debug_toolbar/exception?token=ead4c6c5a3d350eff925&tb=4518219216
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/toolbar.py", line 192, in toolbar_tween
    response = _handler(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/performance.py", line 57, in resource_timer_handler
    result = handler(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.7-py2.7.egg/pyramid/tweens.py", line 21, in excview_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.12-py2.7.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 99, in tm_tween
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.12-py2.7.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 80, in tm_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.7-py2.7.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 163, in handle_request
    response = view_callable(context, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.7-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 355, in rendered_view
    result = view(context, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.7-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 501, in _requestonly_view
    response = view(request)
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssWEB/notssweb/views/views.py", line 32, in form
    assessment = api.retrieve_assessment(request.route_url('assessment', id=id))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notssdb/api/object.py", line 115, in retrieve_assessment
    filter(Assessment.name == something_unique).one()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2478, in one
    raise orm_exc.NoResultFound("No row was found for one()")
NoResultFound: No row was found for one()
```